# How is the concept of aura in Hunter x Hunter?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I have watched HxH 2011 around 1 year ago.

I still wonder how's the concept of aura in HxH? How many types of aura and what kind of each speciality?

> e.g. Enhancer, Manipulator, Specialist, etc.

Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept of Nen in HxH is comparable to Aura, Chakra, Haki, Mana, Magic, etc. from different series. It directly translates to Mind Energy apparently. In this series, it is life energy of the wielder who can manipulate it in different ways.

You can obtain Nen abilities by being exposed to Nen.  Otherwise it takes years of training.

The most basic Nen can be used by any type of Nen user.  These are:

- Ten - put aura around body rather than let it leak out of the body. also protects from other's aura
- Zetsu - stop flow of aura (make yourself less detectable)
- Ren - generate a large amount of aura around oneself for offense
- Hatsu - manifest aura to have special effects

There are other abilities similar the the above which most users can learn to perform but are not "typed": Gyo, In, En, Shu, Ko, Ken, and Ryu are the examples so far.

Some very special users are known as geniuses and learned to use their Nen abilities without mastering the above.  The main examples are the Apraiser and the Fortuneteller.

The form a user's Hatsu takes is controlled by that user.  While in theory any user can master a skill from any of the 5 basic types, they tend to have an affinity for one type and can master it much easier.  Unlike other series, the Nen type is about how you move your aura and not elemental.

- **Conjurors** can turn their Nen into physical objects.  They often has special properties. (summon chains for instance)
- **Transmutors** can change the properties of their Nen and then manipulate that. (turn Nen into electricity and vice versa for instance)
- **Enhancers** apply their Nen to themselves to enhance their own physical abilities. (punch hard for instance)
- **Emitters** push their Nen into projectiles of into other people causing special properties. Sometimes the Nen takes physical shapes such a gorillas, energy balls, mascots, or fists but are still composed of Nen.
- **Manipulators**, finally, put their Nen into other objects and then manipulate that Nen to manipulate that object.

These are grouped so the most similar are near each other.  As Conjuration requires turning you Nen into something else, they find it easier to do Transmutor skills then Manipulator skills, for instance.  Enhancers find it much more difficult to do complex manipulation of Nen in other objects than just emit it as a projectile.

- **Specialists** are special. Their Nen abilities cannot be described as any of the above and are rare.  No other group can learn a Specialist's ability, though a Conjuror or a Manipulator is more likely to become one than any other group.

Finally, very specific Nen abilites are somehow much more powerful than more general use abilities.  Putting restictings on its use, therefore, such as a ritual, target restictions, or delayed activation can make the Nen ability far more powerful.  For this reason, alot of power Nen abilities have complicated rules which must be followed.  Kuripika can only use some abilities on spiders. Gon's attacks have a long charging time and a chant. Chollo has several specific conditions which must be met before he can use his main ability.

Answer (score 4):

@Kaine does a great job at summarizing the basic concept of Nen. I think they missed a few things though. So this anwer just supplements their excellent answer so read ONLY AFTER the first one. I also refer to various links to sources where you can read, if want in more detail.

**Firstly,** the Nen Chart that shows compatibility between Nen Types,
[image]

While talking about Nen, its impossible not to mention this chart. It explains why Enhancers can use Emission or Transmutation more easily then Manipulation or Conjuration. Ex: Gon's Rock-Paper-Scissors are kind of Enhancer, Emmitter and Transmutation attacks. Read more here : Source: [Nen And Individuality - Wikia](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Nen#Nen_and_Individuality)

> There are numerical approximations to indicate just exactly how efficient one would be at using aura abilities that one is not born into. Starting at one's own aura type, one has the potential to be 100% efficient at using abilities based in that category alone. Then looking at the category chart, one has the potential to be 80% efficient at using aura types adjacent to one's primary type, 40% efficient at the opposite or farthest category, and 60% efficient in the two remaining categories. Specialization is typically unusable for non-Specialists because it is impossible to partially use; one either can or cannot use Specialist abilities. However, Conjurers and Manipulators have 1% efficiency potential of becoming Specialists due to being adjacent to it.

**Secondly,** How to find the Nen Nature for an individual?

The most popular and surefire is called the Water Divination Test. Put a Leaf atop a cup full of water and perform *Ren* by putting your hands around the water and voila you know your Nen Type. (Kinda like the Chakra Paper from Naruto).

> - If the volume of the water changes, the user is an Enhancer.
> - If the taste of the water changes, the user is a Transmuter.
> - If impurities appear in the water, the user is a Conjurer.
> - If the color of the water changes, the user is an Emitter.
> - If the leaf moves on the water's surface, the user is a Manipulator.
> - If a completely different change appears, the user is a Specialist.

Hisoka also has a Nen Personality test which is funny but obviously not a surefire way of finding out the Nen Type of individual. But it reveals a lot about the Main Characters personality types since they usually fit the mould.

> - **Enhancers** are determined and simple. Most of them never lie, hide nothing, and are very straightforward in their actions or in their thinking. Their words and actions are often dominated by their feelings. They are generally very selfish and focused on their goals. This is reflected in their Nen as enhancers typically rely on simple and uncomplicated Hatsu techniques.
> - **Transmuters** are whimsical and prone to deceit. Transmutation users have unique attitudes, and many are regarded as weirdos or tricksters. Often they put forth a facade while hiding the truer aspects of their personalities. Even when they don't hide their personalities they rarely reveal their true intentions. Many Transmuters rely on techniques that give unique and unpredictable properties to their Nen that reflects their personalities.
> - **Emitters** are impatient, not detail-oriented, and quick to react in a volatile manner. Many of them are quick-tempered and hot-blooded. They resemble the Enhancers in building their impulsivity, but the difference with them, they probably tend to calm down and forget easier. Because of the nature of Emission, many Hatsu techniques created by emitters are primarily long range.
> - **Conjurers** are typically high-strung or overly serious and stoic. They are often on guard as to be cautious. They are very observant and logical, rarely falling into traps. Being able to analyze things calmly is the strength of Conjurers. Many of the items that conjurers create are often used by them in a very deliberate and practical, logical fashion.
> - **Manipulators** are logical people who advance at their own pace. They are all for arguments and tend to want to keep their families and loved ones safe. On the other hand, when it comes to pursuing their own goals, they do not listen to what others might have to say about it. While manipulators often use techniques that allow them to control their opponents they also prefer to use an inanimate medium to control that can be used versatility (such as smoke or pieces of paper hardened with Shu).
> - **Specialists** are individualistic and charismatic. They won't tell you anything important on them, and refrain from being close friends, but, because of their natural charisma that draws others, they are always surrounded by many people. Because Specialization is unique and can have many facets, most Specialists posses only one Hatsu technique.

Finally, **The Quantification of Nen**. There are various quantified versions of Nen, where you can directly predict the damage incurred as well predict the outcome in very simplistic cases. The article below discusses how much damage would an enhancer attack do to a Conjurer defense if both are using the basic and advance Nen techniques equally.
[Read more here if you are interested in these type of stuff.](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Nen#Quantification_of_Aura)

Comment: Hey thanks I think i got my answer. Its just HxH has to show much to more to us and they are many things which needed to explain in series. Waiting for its manga to start again from where it left. 

I will mark @kaine 's answer because he started correct and you completed it well. But thanks.

Comment: @VishalTarkar Np. I myself agree that Kaine, gave a more complete answer. Cheers~

Answer (score 1):

I too watched HxH twice.

The Aura concept is basically body energy (Nen) . Every person has different type of attribute.

If you saw  Naruto, there is also a concept where their chakra type is decided. Just the same as here.

ONE PiECE - Haki is used to defend, observe, fight & objects can be affected too

- Enhancers is the most powerful because they can use all the  Nen (ten, zetsu, ren, hatsu).
- Conjurers must & should use medium like phone, chains & puppets.
- Specialists are rare like genetics & other special attributes are required.
- Transmuters can change their aura type like Hisoka's Bungee Gum.
- Manipulators manipulate things/humans.
- Emitters are also enhancers but difference is noticeably.

[Here](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Nen)'s a link for you to check out every detail.